# Gradle says "MyPortlet is not assignable to specified service com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet"

Tags: gradle, osgi, portlet, liferay-7

I get this Gradle error:

```
> Task :jar
[Class my.MyPortlet is not assignable to specified service com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet]
```

... for this minimalist Liferay 7 portlet (a simplification of [the official documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/ja/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-an-mvc-portlet)):

```
package my;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
    service = Portlet.class
)
public class MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
}
```

Running Gradle in debug mode does not give me more clues:

```
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] parseClassFile(): path=javax.portlet.PortletRequest resource=:/home/nico/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.portlet/portlet-api/2.0/1cd72f2a37fcf8ab9893a9468d7ba71c85fe2653/portlet-api-2.0.jar(javax/portlet/PortletRequest.class):
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.npm.NpmAnalyzerPlugin@39735dcf
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin@4e811a19
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] parseClassFile(): path=my/MyPortlet.class resource=/home/nico/my/build/classes/java/main/my/MyPortlet.class
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin@526cd630
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.service.ServiceAnalyzerPlugin@a73dc4
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.social.SocialAnalyzerPlugin@2399853a
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin aQute.lib.spring.SpringComponent@650e1282
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] begin com.liferay.ant.bnd.spring.SpringDependencyAnalyzerPlugin@51e79545
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] end
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder] parseClassFile(): path=my/MyPortlet.class resource=/home/nico/my/build/classes/java/main/my/MyPortlet.class
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.npm.NpmAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.service.ServiceAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.social.SocialAnalyzerPlugin
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin aQute.lib.spring.SpringComponent
[aQute.bnd.osgi.Verifier] Trying pre-plugin com.liferay.ant.bnd.spring.SpringDependencyAnalyzerPlugin
[org.dm.gradle.plugins.bundle.JarBuilder] [Class my.MyPortlet is not assignable to specified service com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet]
```

Google has only 9 results for "is not assignable to specified service".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With your source import:

`import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet;`

and then:

`@Component(
    service = Portlet.class
)`

You are asserting that your class `MyPortlet` implements `com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet`. But it does not. `com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet` implements `javax.portlet.Portlet`.

Change you source import from `com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet` to `javax.portlet.Portlet`.

Comment: Thanks I actually just found this it, and posted an answer about it a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

[aQute.bnd.component.AnnotationReader](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bndlib/src/aQute/bnd/component/AnnotationReader.java#L1027) tries to parse the `service = Portlet.class` part and the problem is that [aQute.bnd.osgi.Analyzer.assignable](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bndlib/src/aQute/bnd/osgi/Analyzer.java#L3391)(MyPortlet, com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet) returns false.

Let's follow the class hierarchy:

The portlet implementation in the question
↓
[com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.java)
↓
[com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/portlet/LiferayPortlet.java)
↓
[javax.portlet.GenericPortlet](https://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/GenericPortlet.html)
↓
[javax.portlet.Portlet](https://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/Portlet.html)

This tips us that the import statement is wrong. It should be:

```
import javax.portlet.Portlet;
```

... rather than:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Portlet;
```

After fixing it, the build is successful.